# Azure cosmosdb doesnt show proper value for select count(1) if count is more than 30k. Or if total count is more than 100k.

Tags: azure, count, azure-cosmosdb, aggregation

Azure cosmosdb doesnt show proper value for select count(1) if count is more than 30k. Or if total count is more than 100k. This is without partitioning. Is there any way I can get proper count? I tried using max() along with this,no luck.

Comment: I just tested it and it seems to be working fine as you can see [here](https://i.imgur.com/fI8Wocq.png). How are you querying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my experience, your error is resulted of bottleneck of RUs setting. The `count` query is limited by the number for RUs allocated to your collection. The result that you would have received will have a continuation token(even if on the portal).

You may have 2 solutions:

1.Surely, you could raise the RUs setting.

2.You could keep looking for next set of results via continuation token and keep on adding it so that you will get total count.(Probably in sdk)

I imported exactly 30k documents into my database.Then I tried to run the query

`select value count(1) from c` in Query Explorer. It turns out only partial of total documents every page. So I need to add them all by clicking `Next Page` button.

[image]

Surely, you could do this query in the sdk code via continuation token.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks Jay Gong, it was an issue with less RU/s setting. Now I kept a higher RU, I can see proper result without paging.

Also, only in Query Explorer we can see proper result clicking Next. I usually use Data Explorer query window to write queries, where that option is not available. MS gives a message in Query Explorer not to use it and to use Data Explorer going forward!!!

Comment: @DeveloperArchitect Yes,however it could cause more cost.So maybe query the heavy documents in the sdk is more economical. Anyway,please mark my answer for others' reference on the forum if you think it's useful. Thank you.

Comment: @DeveloperArchitect You could mark my answer if you adopt it.Thanks.

Comment: Not every time we have time to query sdk, we need to create a client app for ourselves otherwise. RU/s is fixed for the plan, we were not utilizing entire throughput. Increased it to utilize to its entire capacity and that fixed the issue. Thanks for the help!